# Git Extensions usable with SVN repos?

Tags: windows, git, svn

Can Git Extensions be used without issues (or at least, with very few ones) as a SVN client? I've no problem using the command-line git-svn, but in some cases (picking lines/hunks to commit, for example) I'd rather use a GUI client.

If there are issues, I'd like to see them along with your workarounds/solutions.

Comment: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/4592 and also https://github.com/mast-eu/GitExtensions.SVN/wiki/Workarounds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a way of an updated answer (I think this question was asked in 2011), I just started using Git Extensions for a project that uses Subversion as the repo, but I wanted to use Git locally. Learning my way into it, Git Extensions has GUI based actions for commands like SVN Fetch, SVN Rebase, and SVN Dcommit.

So, if (and I don't know because I wasn't using it in 2011) Git Extensions didn't support Subversion repos in 2011, it looks like they have that support now.

Here is an example (see red highlights at bottom):

[image]

So, to better answer your question, yes it does have support as an SVN/Git client.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to this, with an extra upvote :). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`git-svn` creates a repository that behaves as a regular Git repository unless you are doing one of it's special operations (`dcommit` etc.). Thus, it is perfectly fine to interact with that repository via any external Git client as long as you use it to do things you'd normally be able to do from the command line without screwing up `git-svn`. (E.g. you wouldn't want to try to rebase upstream commits, GUI or not.)

(You will, of course, still have to use the command line for the special `git-svn` commands, unless you find a GUI that supports them.)

Comment: I'm guessing there aren't a lot of Git GUI tools that can be used for interacting with SVN repos. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the answer from Amber: you could also add custom commands to the user interface in GitExtensions. Just check out the scripts tab in the configuration dialog. You could for example add new buttons to the gitextensions user interface. You can also add execute custom commands right before/after key actions like commit/push/pull.

Answer (score 2):

As alluded to by @matth, SVN support was [removed from Git Extensions v3.00](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/713). However, there is a plugin ([mast-eu/GitExtensions.SVN](https://github.com/mast-eu/GitExtensions.SVN)) you can install to add basic `git svn` commands to Git Extensions. To install it, open *Plugins* > *Plugin Manager* and browse for "gitextensions.svn".

Once installed, SVN commands are added to menu bar.

[Picture of menu bar with commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytuRt.png)